# Flask SqlAlchemy DB2 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

i'm trying to figure out the Uri string to connect correctly to db2 using flask with SqlAlchemy.

I've tried with

> - db2:///?Server=server&;Port=50000&User=admin&Password=admin&Database=test"
> - 'ibm_db_sa+pyodbc400://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database};currentSchema={schema}

Any clue for the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record the correct format (at least for me) is

```
ibm_db_sa://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}
```

Also you need a few libraries to install via pip in order to work with alembic+flask

- ibm_db
- ibm_db_sa
- ibm_db_alembic (https://pypi.org/project/ibm_db_alembic/)

In the ibm_db_alembic document is a typo in the description usage, the correct one to import is

> `from ibm_db_alembic.ibm_db import IbmDbImpl`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'ibm_db_sa://enter_user:enter_password@enter_host:50000/BLUDB'

# for secure
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'ibm_db_sa://enter_user:enter_password@enter_host:50001/BLUDB;SECURITY=SSL;sslCertLocation=path/to/cer_file.cer;sslConnection=true;'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'enter_table_name'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"enter_shema_name"}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(256), index=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(256))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(256))
    email = db.Column(db.String(256))


db.create_all()
```

If you need to generate fake data for the test, you can do it with the following piece of code:

```py
from faker import Faker


def create_fake_users(n):
    """Generate fake users."""
    faker = Faker()
    for i in range(n):
        user = User(name=faker.name(),
                    age=random.randint(20, 80),
                    address=faker.address().replace('\n', ', '),
                    phone=faker.phone_number(),
                    email=faker.email())
        db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    print(f'Added {n} fake users to the database.')
```

And then the generated data can be sent to display in your template:

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    users = User.query
    return render_template('your_template.html', title='Fake Users',
                           users=users)
```

And you can easily display the content in `block content`

```html
{% block content %}
  <table id="data" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.address }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```